# Why can't I add an element to another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, jupyter-notebook, element

When i type `X_all.HM1 = X_all.HM1.astype('str')`

I get the error :  `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'HM1'`

Why do I get this error and how can I fix this?

the whole code:

````
# Separate into feature set and target variable
#FTR = Full Time Result (H=Home Win, D=Draw, A=Away Win)
X_all = data.drop(['FTR'],1)
y_all = data['FTR']

# Standardising the data.
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale

#Center to the mean and component wise scale to unit variance.
cols = [['HTGD','ATGD','HTP','ATP','DiffLP']]
for col in cols:
    X_all[col] = scale(X_all[col]

#last 3 wins for both sides
X_all.HM1 = X_all.HM1.astype('str')
X_all.HM2 = X_all.HM2.astype('str')
X_all.HM3 = X_all.HM3.astype('str')
X_all.AM1 = X_all.AM1.astype('str')
X_all.AM2 = X_all.AM2.astype('str')
X_all.AM3 = X_all.AM3.astype('str')

#we want continous vars that are integers for our input data, so lets remove any categorical vars
def preprocess_features(X):
    ''' Preprocesses the football data and converts catagorical variables into dummy variables. '''
    
    # Initialize new output DataFrame
    output = pd.DataFrame(index = X.index)

    # Investigate each feature column for the data
    for col, col_data in X.iteritems():

        # If data type is categorical, convert to dummy variables
        if col_data.dtype == object:
            col_data = pd.get_dummies(col_data, prefix = col)
                    
        # Collect the revised columns
        output = output.join(col_data)
    
    return output

X_all = preprocess_features(X_all)
print "Processed feature columns ({} total features):\n{}".format(len(X_all.columns), list(X_all.columns))```
````

Comment: Please share your code, it's hard to debug with no context

Comment: It looks like the problem isn't that code specifically but your implementation of the HM1 method. But as Prateek said, can't know for sure without code.

Comment: I just updated my post with the whole code, I am trying to get the last three wins for both sides of football teams

Comment: What is X? where is the HM1 method? and where is the X_all class?

Comment: just updated the post again with more code

Comment: try printing out your columns. it just means, exactly as the error says, that your dataframe has no column/attribute `HM1`.

Comment: also instead of trying to type the error out, copy/paste it. the actual error will look something like: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'HM1'`

Comment: That's the issue, how do I add the attribute correctly?

Comment: `df['HM1'] = data`. regarding what you want this data to be, you have to figure it out. but that's how you assign a column to a dataframe.

Comment: and in case you're confused about your error, it's happening on the _right_ side of your assignment. just try printing `df.HM1` and see what happens. you'll get the same error.